# "All boot options are tried" after updating BIOS

Tags: windows-8, bios

I have a Samsung series five laptop. I recently updated the BIOS, which completed successfully.

I got the following message after it rebooted:

```
All boot options are tried. Press <F4> key to recover with factory image using Recovery or any other keys for next boot loop iteration.
```

Pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> does nothing. I have checked the BIOS boot menu and it does not have a "Windows Boot Manager". How should I solve this?

```
**Secure Boot Configuration**
UEFI Secure Boot          Enabled
Protected Signatures      Enabled (User Mode)
Customized Signatures     Disabled (Standard Mode)
CertNames                 Win8 Certificates
```

Comment: do you have a 'boot' section in your BIOS that defines the order and use of your boot up? It's possible the BIOS update cleared any original settings

Comment: Does the HDD show up at all in the BIOS?  Can you boot from a bootable DVD or USB key?

Comment: sounds like you can't enter the bios? (otherwise i wonder what you are doing!). You write " which completed successfully"  you mean CLAIMS TO HAVE completed successfully!  IF you can't enter the BIOS that is odd.  maybe you should flash it again and cal samsung and post your answer.

Comment: The HDD does show up in the BIOS. However, there used to be a Windows Boot Manager option which came first. It is not there anymore

Comment: To get even more relevant comments, _edit your question_ and add information about (a) the "Secure Boot" setting in your firmware SETUP utility, and (b) the "OS mode selection" setting in the same.

Comment: @JdeBP I don't seem to have an OS mode selection setting in my setup

Comment: It only appears when "Secure Boot" is disabled.  That's why I mentioned "Secure Boot" first.

Comment: You are very unclear. Are you able to boot into Windows?  (I ask 'cos you can apparently get into the BIOS). . By the way, this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1dadf0b1-5c0f-4a6e-b7ff-9b9eaf4f66a9/all-boot-options-are-tried-cannot-start-computer?forum=samsungpcgeneral   mentions that error but that guy says he can't get into the BIOS. The problem is on "secure boot"

Go to bios setting

Chose Boot and then disabled "secure boot "

then on Os Made Selection change to ( CSM and UEFI OS )

after finish go to exit chose "save changes configuration and reset"

Comment: @barlop I cannot boot into Windows but can boot into the BIOS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This post on [social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1dadf0b1-5c0f-4a6e-b7ff-9b9eaf4f66a9/all-boot-options-are-tried-cannot-start-computer?forum=samsungpcgeneral) mentions that error. An answer says that the problem is the "secure boot" setting. Go to BIOS, choose "Boot", and then disable "Secure Boot". Then change OS Mode Selection to `CSM and UEFI OS`. After you finish, exit choose "save changes/configuration and reset"

Comment: the questioner on that post says he can't get into the bios but no doubt he can on starting, but not by the time it offers him F4

Comment: often error messages are more useful as things to google than their content. It's great that you gave the exact words of the error. If you'd googled that error message it's possible you'd have hit on the answer as I did.