# All boot options are tried loop

Tags: boot, usb, windows-8.1, bios

I have read several questions and answers from different sites including:

["All boot options are tried" after updating BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/708852/all-boot-options-are-tried-after-updating-bios?newreg=ab223e39a34845d2a77a0139cb3ba1c1)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1dadf0b1-5c0f-4a6e-b7ff-9b9eaf4f66a9/all-boot-options-are-tried-cannot-start-computer?forum=samsungpcgeneral

With no success.

I have a Samsung series 5 ultrabook, in which I installed an Original version of Windows 8.1 from a bootable USB (created using Rufus). Everything worked fine, Windows is already installed on my hard drive, however when I tried to restart the laptop I get this message:

```
All boot options are tried. Press <F4> key to recover with factory image using 
Recovery or any other keys for next boot loop iteration.
```

I disabled Fast BIOS and Secure Boot and selected UEFI and CMS mode (tried the other 2 also), but still gives me the exact same message.

What is more strange is that whenever I connect a bootable USB, I get this:

```
Press any key to start from USB...
```

If I don't press anything it goes and starts my Windows 8.1, but if I do not connect the USB I get the "all options are tried" message.

I've been researching this for a few days now, even contacted Samsung India which is where I bought but don't live there so it's not that easy to help me.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE: model NP530U4C-S03IN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after days of trying to fix my samsung laptop I found this great article:

http://arktronic.com/weblog/2012-08-05/how-do-clean-install-windows-7-or-8-samsung-chronos-laptops/

I'm goint to add a few steps of my own specific for samsung series 5 with ssd for fast boot laptops:

1. Boot off the Windows DVD or USB installation media
2. Choose the "Repair" option, and the command prompt afterwards (the way to get there is different between Windows 7 and 8)
3. Type in diskpart to get into the partition tool
4. Use the commands list disk and list part to determine which disk is what. For me, Disk 0 was the HDD and Disk 1 was the SSD. The following instructions assume this
5. Select the HDD: sel disk 0
6. Delete all partitions on it: clean
7. Create a 100MB partition for Windows 7 (change to 350MB for Windows 8): create part primary size=100 (or size=350)
8. Format it: format fs=ntfs quick
9. Assign it a letter: assign letter=f (if F: is in use, pick another one. Use list vol to see all volumes and their letters)
10. Create a partition that fills the rest of the disk: create part primary
11. Format it and assign it letter "C", as above
12. Select the SSD: sel disk 1
13. Delete all partitions on it: clean
14. Reboot back into the Windows installation media and install Windows into the large partition that was just created
15. Again, reboot into the Windows installation media and go into the repair command prompt
16. Use diskpart's list vol and assign commands to ensure that both the boot partition (F:) and the Windows partition (C:) still have drive letters if not reassign them with C and F as before
17. Again wipe down SSD disk as in 12 and 13
18. Select the boot partition (sel part 1) and mark it as active: active
19. Exit diskpart and type in: bcdboot c:\windows /s f:

So, at first I tried the exact same steps as the guide but windows still created the System Reserved partition on the SSD making it impossible to boot properly. I decided to give it another try with the corrections above and worked!

After all, I wanted to use ExpressCache for fast boot with the SSD so I retrieved all drivers from Samsung (like SW Update which is actually the most useful), installed everything recommended (including settings which is necessary for the ExpressCache). After all rebooted and installed ExpressCache and now everything is working fine!

Notes: After booting to my win8 I checked my disks partitions to verify that the SSD wasn't used and that the full of it was unallocated for ExpressCache to format it properly.

Hope this helps somebody 'cause it took me days to find this :)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problems but, I solved with some changes on Bios setup. I restarting a client's laptop with Win 7 that I recently installed, then I updated some drivers from Samsung Website. After that, the system wasn't starting and appears: "All boot options are tried. Press  key to recover with factory image using Recovery or any other keys for next boot loop iteration." whaaatt??.. I said confused.

After reviewing some post and pages on internet I've solved the problem. It located in the same Bios, you need to restart the laptop again and press Tab, then Tab again to obtain option "Setup", then Secure Boot and locate disable Secure Boot, then on Os mode selection change to "UEFI OS and CSM" then, save and exit setup and restart your laptop again.

It works well, my client was happy with me. Thanks a lot for this post man.
Greetings form Colombia South America..

Answer (score 0):

Did you erase the system rebuild partition from the Samsung HDD? If you don't know press F4 when asked and see if you get the start of the system rebuild.

If you do, Use easeus partition manager to remove the partition and expand the free space into the Windows 8 partition.

You will then need to run the Windows 8 repair using the USB installer. Remove the USB stick before you run the repair.

If still no joy wipe the HDD completely with gparted on a USB linux installer, creating a new partition table from the menu. Once you have done this reinstall Windows 8.

Comment: The problem is that this laptop has 2 disks. One in which I installed windos HDD, and an SSD 24GB disk which was supposed to be for fast boot. I've downloaded every possible sw from Samsung and install all of it and still can't boot properly :(. The recovery partition is gone and was expanded to Windows 8 partition.

Comment: Try swapping over the disks. The SSD (24gb seems very small) should be the primary. Then run the Windows 8 repair again.