# Samsung Notebook BIOS Failure after update

Tags: windows-7, windows, uefi

Regarding the thread "[All boot options are tried loop](https://superuser.com/questions/825304/all-boot-options-are-tried-loop)" (after updating BIOS), i wanna thank Barlop (Applied his suggestion and it worked!), for the help and ask... What should i do now??? keep these settings for the BIOS? isnt this cause any problems in the future?
 .
What he suggested and i did:
"Go to bios setting Chose Boot and then disabled "secure boot " then on Os Made Selection change to (CSM and UEFI OS)"

Comment: It would be usefull to have a reference to the original question/answer. Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/842517/edit) your question and link to the original question/answer

Comment: Tnx! I ve actually tried to comment on the same post, but i was unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, only the settings for BIOS are broken. If you installed Windows using UEFI, it keeps using UEFI. No way it can change to MBR. Also, disabling secure boot, while not recommended for the casual user, is not so great an issue, since until a few years back we didn't have it at all.

So basically, you computer is now having compatibility code in memory, but doesn't use it and secure boot is gone. You may use it like this without any problem whatsoever, but suggestion would be to revert the BIOS back to the older one. As a thumb rule, don't update the BIOS unless it is broken or yours is too old. You can also try waiting to see if another update fixes the problem.