# Ssd can be read from windows but not recognised in bios

Tags: ssd, bios

My computer developed an intermittent fault stopped booting up as the SSD could not be recognized, this turned into a permanent fault.  I google around and tried [All boot options are tried loop](https://superuser.com/questions/825304/all-boot-options-are-tried-loop). I have tried both UEFI and CSM boot options. I then installed windows 10 from a boot DVD on a different HD and everything is working normally.

Here is where it gets weird.  I was able to copy my files off the SSD from within windows 10 but it can't be seen in the bios. I have since formatted the SSD.

What is wrong with my SSD?

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online          465 GB      0 B        *

DISKPART> sel disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list part

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Recovery           499 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    System              99 MB   500 MB
  Partition 3    Reserved            16 MB   599 MB
  Partition 4    Primary            465 GB   615 MB
```

Comment: Do you have CSM enabled or disabled?  CSM is sometimes called Legacy Mode, in order to use your SSD, you really should enable UEFI only mode.  As always edit your question to include this vital information required to answer your question.

Comment: If your laptop is still under warranty, try to get the ssd checked or replaced. May be bad contact in the sata connector. I had a similar issue once, ssd was too slow to start to register with the bios. After firmware update it improved.